# Finding the nearest number in an array of objects with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am not working with a flat array of numbers, I need context with the numbers i.e whether it's a start point or an endpoint.

I'm confused about how to evaluate which number is closest to a specific number.

```
const dataStructure = [{
  uid: "123",
  startTime: 2,
  endTime: 6
}, {
  uid: "345",
  startTime: 9,
  endTime: 15
}]
```

I'm tracking a node's coordinates on drag, when moving left the number to evaluate is its `x` coordinate, when moving right I am tracking the `x` coordinate plus the width. Either way, one number is produced and I am trying to evaluate which point is closest to my number. It can either be the startTime or the endTime.

But I need to know if it's start/end and the uid of the matching element.

I'm trying to put together in my head the logic for the reducer, but can't quite figure it out

```
const updatingTime = 6.7;

// TODO: Out of the two elements, which one is the closest, and which edge is the closest i.e start or end?
dataStructure.reduce((acc: any, curr: any) => {
  const lastEnd = acc.endTime;
  const lastStart = acc.startTime;
  const currEnd = curr.endTime;
  const currStart = curr.startTime;

  // find the node with either start or end closest to 6.7
  // also return key that was the best match i.e startTime/endTime

  return curr;
});

// if our number is 6.7 then uid: "123" is our answer with "end" being the edge
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to go too fast in devising a solution. Start simpler: write a function to return the closest element going off of the start time (the uid and the distance from the start time). Then, modify this method to make it dependent on the key. You could call this more general method with  the keys "endTime" and "startTime" and your answer could be a comparison of the results of those calls.

Comment: Good point, let me try that

Comment: Is it always: `dataStructure[i].start < dataStructure[i].end`, `dataStructure[0].end < dataStructure[1].start` and `dataStructure.length === 2`?

Comment: length can be n eventually as I iterate on this codebase. Its detecting elements to snap to within a video editing timeline. So in most cases, it checks one element above and one element below. Decides the closest one and which edge is most appropriate to snap to. I can see a time where it will look at multiple tracks above and below

Comment: Is a structure with overlap like `[{ uid: "123", startTime: 2, endTime: 9 }, { uid: "345", startTime: 6, endTime: 15 }]` possible? What's the expected result of `[{ uid: "123", startTime: 2, endTime: 3 }, { uid: "345", startTime: 5, endTime: 6 }]` and updatingTime `4` (updating time in the middle of two points)?

Comment: Yeah most definitely, good question. Here is a UI example https://share.getcloudapp.com/BluKNopp

Answer (score 1):

You can find the smallest distance by finding the minimum difference between the start or end time.

```js
const data = [
  { uid: "123", startTime: 2, endTime:  6 },
  { uid: "345", startTime: 9, endTime: 15 }
];

const findClosest = (data, deltaFn, target) =>
  data.reduce((prev, curr) =>
    deltaFn(curr, target) - deltaFn(prev, target) < 0 ? curr : prev);

const minDiff = ({ startTime, endTime }, target) =>
  Math.min(Math.abs(startTime - target), Math.abs(endTime - target));

const closest = findClosest(data, minDiff, 6.7);

console.log(closest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This looks nice, trying it out also, probably better than what I came up with. Would be curious if this has any advantages over what I posted below?

Comment: It works nice, I need to make a small modification and return which edge we need to snap to inside the reduce function. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution following @bearacuda13's suggestion of simplifying the solution

```
const closest = ({ key, items }: any) =>
  items.reduce((acc: any, curr: any) =>
    Math.abs(curr[key] - updatingTime) < Math.abs(acc[key] - updatingTime) ? curr : acc
  );

const findClosestStart = closest({ key: "startTime", items: closestEls });
const findClosestEnd = closest({ key: "endTime", items: closestEls });
const a = Math.abs(findClosestStart.startTime - updatingTime);
const b = Math.abs(findClosestEnd.endTime - updatingTime);

const which = a < b ? findClosestStart : findClosestEnd;

console.log({ which });
```

Seems like this works not quite sure about performance and or edge cases.